# How to implement nested serializers in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i'm trying to implement nested serializers.

Serializers.py

```
class BranchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Branch
        fields = '__all__'

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

to override branch in studentserializers and import branch details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class BranchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Branch
        fields = '__all__'

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    branch = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Branch.objects.all())

    # to get single field name.
    # branch = serializers.CharField(source = 'branch.branch_name') 

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```